# How do I enable namespacing on an imported VueX module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, namespaces, vuex

I'm using a helper file to import VueX modules:

```
const requireModule = require.context('.', false,  /\.store\.js$/)
const modules = {}

requireModule.keys().forEach(filename => {
    const moduleName = filename
                   .replace(/(\.\/|\.store\.js)/g, '')
                   .replace(/^\w/, c => c.toUpperCase())
    modules[moduleName] = requireModule(filename).default || requireModule(filename)
})

export default modules
```

This lives in @/store/modules/index.js and is imported by @/store/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import modules from './modules'

Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules,
  actions: {
    reset({commit}) {
      Object.keys(modules).forEach(moduleName => {
        commit(`${moduleName}/RESET`);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Imported in to Vue: @/main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Works great for all of my store modules!  Each of which are namespaced:

```
const initialState = () => ({})
const state = initialState()
const mutations = {
  RESET(state) {
    const newState = initialState();
    Object.keys(newState).forEach(key => {
          state[key] = newState[key]
    });
  }
} 
const getters = {}
const actions = {}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

Now, I'm trying to import a package as a state module.  Which I don't have any experience with.  This might seem silly... but I'm not sure how to inject the namespace enablement into the package importation in @/store/modules/Auth.store.js:

```
import AmazonCognitoVuexModule from 'amazon-cognito-vuex-module';

const cognito = new AmazonCognitoVuexModule({
  region: process.env.VUE_APP_COGNITO_REGION,
  userPoolId: process.env.VUE_APP_COGNITO_USERPOOL_ID,
  clientId: process.env.VUE_APP_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
})

export default cognito
```

So when I try to call the imported store module's actions with $store.dispatch('Auth/...') they're not found... because they're not namespaced.  I want to namespace this module "Auth".  I bet I'm overlooking something really simple.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My first try would be (based on the docs of this package on NPM):

```
// source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-vuex-module
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    cognito: new AmazonCognitoVuexModule({
      region: '<region>',
      userPoolId: '<user pool id>',
      clientId: '<client id>'
    })
  }
});
```

The code above shows that you can import it as a module (they named it `cognito`, you want `auth` - that should make no difference; I use the naming in the official docs). So you need to update your code, like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import modules from './modules'
import cognito from './path/to/cognito'

Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    ...modules,
    cognito,
  },
  actions: {
    reset({commit}) {
      Object.keys(modules).forEach(moduleName => {
        commit(`${moduleName}/RESET`);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

I'm not sure this works, but this would be my first try :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  It is not that I'm unable to import the store module.  That works fine as a separate file, using the importation helper.  Your answer seems to just eliminate that... which I don't want to do.  What I need help with is enabling the namespaced property on the imported store.  The package documentation doesn't describe how to pass that value.

Comment: @robwolf.io yes - but if `cognito` is a module like the others, then you could `export default { ...cognito, namespaced: true }`. At least try if that works. Or try `cognito.namespaced: true` and `export` that.